# Hide part of url in angular 2/4

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am using angular 4 .I have a situation where i have to route to another component by using router.navigate like following.

```
url="/screenpath/firstScreen"
this._router.navigate(["/path/guided/"+url]);
```

which will be route as

```
localhost:4200/path/guided/screenpath/firstScreen
```

Setting of url is dynamic based on the screenPath i am getting from the rest end point.Now my **question** is

1. Is it possible to hide the url part from being shown in the browser.I dont want to hide the full url but only "url" ie i want to show only

> localhost:4200/path/guided/

I know skipLocationChange will hide the url.But this hides the whole url which i dont want.

Please help.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I guess you can manually replace the url on component init: window.history.pushState("", "", '/path/guided'); keep in mind that this url will be in your browser history so don't forget to handle this

Comment: component init of which component ? The one i am landing in ? The url is fetched from backend and there are hundreds of possible components,do i have to do this  in all the components ?

Comment: I think a batter approach will be to create a service that listen to route change.. If your url contains some url ("screenpath" for example) then change the url

Comment: You can possibly use data argument for a route. For example: {path: 'some-path', component: Cmp , data: {screen: 'first'} }

Comment: @bharath i want the user to see the part of the url.!

Comment: @Gili dis there any resource you can direct me to ?

Comment: I've added an answer with an example. Hope's it will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the url manually like this:

```
 window.history.pushState("", "", '/path/guided/');
```

Keep in mind that this url will be saved in browser history so you should handle cases of user route directly to /path/guided.

Because its something you want you be general in many components I suggest you use a service for it.

service.ts:

```
import {NavigationEnd} from "@angular/router";

routerObservableInstance$;

 constructor(private router: Router){
  this.subscribeToRouteChange();
}

subscribeToRouteChange(){
   this.routerObservableInstance$ = this.
   .router
   .events
   .filter(event=>event instanceof NavigationEnd)
   subscribe(event => {
   if(event.urlAfterRedirects.indexOf('screenpath')!=-1){
      window.history.pushState("", "", '/path/guided/');
   }
 }
}

onDestroy(){
  this.routerObservableInstance.unsubscribe();
}
```

In the service you subscribe to any route change and filter out only events of type 'NavigationEnd' (Imported from @angular/router).Then you should check your router url and if it contains screenpath (Or any other string you decide) you change the route to /path/guided.